# Mathematically lossless encoding and decoding of RGB24 image sequence

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, codec, video-encoding

I am trying to encode a RGB24 image sequence into a mathematically (**not merely visually**) lossless video. huffyuv was suggested on many online forums so I tried the following.

```
ffmpeg -i frames\%06d.png  -vcodec huffyuv test.avi
```

The resulting video was then decoded into frames again using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i test.avi outframes\%06d.png
```

However, the input and output frames are not bit-by-bit identical as promised by huffyuv [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffyuv). Any idea how I can accomplish this? My eventual goal is to read the video file using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)  but I am willing to cross that bridge later once I obtain a losslessly encoded video file.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701805/h264-lossless-coding) mentions an attempt to obtain a lossless h264 avi and the summary of responses seems to indicate h264 cannot completely accomplish lossless encoding.

Once again, to emphasize, **I am interested in bit-by-bit identical encoding, not just visually similar**. Large file sizes are acceptable as is large compression/decompression time.

Comment: For what purpose? - what is it you intend to accomplish with the result of this operation that you cannot accomplish with the image sequence, or a zip/tarball of the image sequence?

Comment: Note that the bitwise differences you see likely arise from the rgb/yuv conversion rather than the compression. If you need input and output RGB images to be bitwise identical you'll probably want a means of encoding video that works in RGB colourspace.

Comment: One reason is that I need the data to be copied over the network and I do not want to copy the image sequence. From what I have read, huffyuv produces a decent compression, although it obviously would not match a lossly compression size. The other reason is convenience. I would like to be able to read the file as an avi.

Comment: @moonshadow huffyuv can work with RGB colorspace as mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffyuv)

Comment: ffmpeg -vcodec ffv1 -pix_fmt rgb24 is probably your best bet

Comment: @moonshadow I tried `ffmpeg -vcodec ffv1 -pix_fmt rgb24`. Results are visually similar but not bitwise. One suspicion I have is about the comparison process. The png image sequence was produced using OpenCV's `cvSaveImage()`. However, I use MATLAB's `imread` to load the original and decoded-from-avi frames. I am going to try using OpenCV to read the images for comparison.

Comment: Are you certain that the differences are in actual RGB values rather than how they are encoded in .png format? Different png encodes will give a different bytestream for the exact same picture.

Comment: Using the MD5 muxer in ffmpeg will probably be useful for your comparisons as shown in [How to compare two lossless media files?](http://superuser.com/a/532223/110524).

Comment: Use the approach described in the link you already added above, it actually works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701805/h264-lossless-coding/12303936#18506577