# Writing frames from camera using skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-capture, scikits

I'm trying to finely control the video encoding of camera image frames captured on the fly using `skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter` and `cv2.VideoCapture`, e.g.

```
from skvideo import io
import cv2

fps = 60
stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)                    # 0 is for /dev/video0
print("fps: {}".format(stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)))

stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
print("bit_depth: {}".format(stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, cv2.CV_8U)))

video = io.FFmpegWriter('/tmp/test_ffmpeg.avi', 
            inputdict={'-r': fps, '-width': 1920, '-height': 1080},
            outputdict={'-r': fps, '-vcodec': 'libx264', '-pix_fmt': 'h264'}
)

try:
    for i in range(fps*10):  # 10s of video
        ret, frame = stream.read()
        video.writeFrame(frame)
finally:
    stream.release()

try:
    video.close()
except:
    pass
```

However, I get the following exception (in Jupyter notebook):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-33-007a547c4229> in <module>()
     18     while range(fps*10):
     19         ret, frame = stream.read()
---> 20         video.writeFrame(frame)
     21 except BaseException as err:
     22     raise err

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skvideo/io/ffmpeg.py in writeFrame(self, im)
    446         T, M, N, C = vid.shape
    447         if not self.warmStarted:
--> 448             self._warmStart(M, N, C)
    449 
    450         # Ensure that ndarray image is in uint8

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skvideo/io/ffmpeg.py in _warmStart(self, M, N, C)
    412         cmd = [_FFMPEG_PATH + "/" + _FFMPEG_APPLICATION, "-y"] + iargs + ["-i", "-"] + oargs + [self._filename]
    413 
--> 414         self._cmd = " ".join(cmd)
    415 
    416         # Launch process

TypeError: sequence item 3: expected str instance, int found
```

Changing this to `video.writeFrame(frame.tostring())` results in `ValueError: Improper data input`, leaving me stumped.

How should I go about writing each frame (as returned by OpenCV) to my FFmpegWriter instance?

## EDIT

The code works fine if I remove `inputdict` and `outputdict` from the `io.FFmpegWriter` call, however this defeats the purpose for me as I need fine control over the video encoding (I am experimenting with lossless/near-lossless compression of the raw video captured from the camera and trying to establish the best compromise in terms of compression vs fidelity for my needs).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few points to note here:

- `skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter` uses the `ffmpeg` command line tool to encode videos, not the C API. So test your `ffmpeg` command in terminal first to make sure you've a working pipeline.
- The `inputdict={},outputdict={}` take string inputs not integers. If you've an integer variable then use `str(var_name)` to convert it to string.
- You've to make sure the `pix_fmt` you're using is supported by the codec. To get a list of all `pix_fmt`s use `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`. Keep in mind that `x264` does not accept all the `pix_fmt`s that `ffmpeg` internally supports.

So for a near lossless encoding (see [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#LosslessH.264) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18506577/2286337)) we can use the following command:

`ffmpeg -s 1920x1080 -r 60 -i /dev/video0 -s 1920x1080 -r 60 -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv444p test_ffmpeg.avi`

The same command translated to `skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter` would be:

```
fps = 60
width = 1920
height = 1080
crf = 17
video = io.FFmpegWriter('/tmp/test_ffmpeg.avi', 
            inputdict={'-r': str(fps), '-s':'{}x{}'.format(width,height)},
            outputdict={'-r': str(fps), '-c:v': 'libx264', '-crf': str(crf), '-preset': 'ultrafast', '-pix_fmt': 'yuv444p'}
)
```

Comment: Thank you @zindarod for your explanation - it helped a lot!

Comment: The [doc](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/modules/generated/skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter.html#skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter.__init__) said `Does not instantiate the an FFmpeg subprocess, but simply prepares the required parameters.`