# Is it possible to reduce or compress video size without quality loss in Android or having any library or we can do it programmatically

Tags: video, compression

I want to reduce the video size with loss less quality, Is there any library, I have found telegram library but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean zero loss compression then you will need to compress with a codec that supports that.

There are ways to achieve lossless encoding with common codecs like h.264 and its open source version x264 - see this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18506577/334402

You will most likely need to use ffmpeg - the easiest way to use this on Android in my experience is via a wrapper library. This is one of the popular ones for example: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: Yes you can use this query.....  {"-y","-i",inputPath.mp4,"-s","160x120","-r","25","-vcodec","mpeg4","-b:v","150k","-b:a","48000","ac","2","-ar","22050",output.mp4}

Comment: it is giving very low quality video